# How to save JSON returned in a javascript function as a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, function, variables, ip-address

Im trying to save the client IP address in a variable after retrieving it in JSON form from api.ipify.org. I can get the IP to show if I alert the result but cannot get it to save in a variable for some reason.

This works:

```
<script>

function getIP(json) {
    alert(json.ip);
}

</script>
<script src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

But this does not work:

```
<script>

var clientIP = ''

function getIP(json) {
    clientIP = json.ip;
    return clientIP;
}

alert(clientIP);

</script>
<script src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

I would like to be able to store the data in a variable so that I can attach it to an embed that will add it into its automated webhook POST.

```
<!-- begin video recorder code --><script type="text/javascript">
var IPADDRESSVARIABLE = 'SOME_IP_ADDRESS'
var size = {width:400,height:330};
var flashvars = {qualityurl: "avq/300p.xml",accountHash:"BUNCHOFRANDOMSTUFF", eid:2, showMenu:"true", mrt:120,sis:0,asv:1,mv:0, payload: IPADDRESSVARIABLE};
(function() {var pipe = document.createElement('script'); pipe.type = 'text/javascript'; pipe.async = true;pipe.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 's1.addpipe.com/1.3/pipe.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(pipe, s);})();
</script>
<div id="hdfvr-content"> </div>
<!-- end video recorder code -->
```

If I can get the IP address saved as a global variable then I can pass it into the 'payload' key of the 'flash vars'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround! I stored the result of the IP function into a hidden div to act as a container. I then declared a variable inside the embed code and set it to the  innerHMTL. It may not be the most elegant but it does exactly what I want it to!

```
//hidden container to store the client IP address
<div id = 'ipContainer' style='display:none'></div>

//function to retrieve the client IP address
<script>
function getIP(json) {
    document.getElementById('ipContainer').innerHTML = json.ip;
}
</script>

//shortened version of the URL that returns the IP
<script src='http://www.api.ipify.org'><script>


//embed code for the video recorder
<script>
<!-- begin video recorder code --><script type="text/javascript">
var clientIP = document.getElementById('ipContainer').innerHTML;
var size = {width:400,height:330};


//I passed the clientIP variable into the payload element of the flashvars object
var flashvars = {qualityurl: "avq/300p.xml",accountHash:"RANDOM ACCOUNT HASH", eid:2, showMenu:"true", mrt:120,sis:0,asv:1,mv:0, payload:clientIP}; //Here i passed the clientIP which is nor stored as a variable
(function() {var pipe = document.createElement('script'); pipe.type = 'text/javascript'; pipe.async = true;pipe.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 's1.addpipe.com/1.3/pipe.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(pipe, s);})();
</script>
<div id="hdfvr-content"> </div>
<!-- end video recorder code -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `alert` won't work because your code is not executing synchronously, `getIP` doesn't get called until *after* your `alert` statement. You need to trigger any functionality that depends on `clientIP` inside your `getIP` function. Here is an example:

```js
function getIP(json) {
   var event = new CustomEvent('iploaded', { detail: json.ip });
   document.dispatchEvent(event);
}

document.addEventListener('iploaded', function(event) {
   var IPADDRESSVARIABLE = event.detail;
   var size = {width:400,height:330};
   var flashvars = {qualityurl: "avq/300p.xml",accountHash:"BUNCHOFRANDOMSTUFF", eid:2, showMenu:"true", mrt:120,sis:0,asv:1,mv:0, payload: IPADDRESSVARIABLE};
   (function() {var pipe = document.createElement('script'); pipe.type = 'text/javascript'; pipe.async = true;pipe.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 's1.addpipe.com/1.3/pipe.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(pipe, s);})();
});

// simulate jsonp callback
getIP({ ip: '127.0.0.1' });
```

Also, no need to `return` in `getIP`

Comment: So im not actually trying to alert the IP address. This is just me trying to figure out how to store the ip itself into a variable so that I can send it in some flash vars forcing it to get sent through a third party webhook to my php handler. So my end goal is to get the ip into a global variable.

Comment: Nice answer, although it's not strictly true that he needs to put any code that depends on clientIP inside the getIP function. He could pass the clientIP to a webworker which could be in a different file, or trigger a custom event ( passing the clientIp with it).

Comment: Couldn't you just use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in PHP?

Comment: @RobM. Im sorry if I'm not understanding correctly so would I then pass getIP(); into the embed code flahsvars?

Comment: Also the problem for me using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is that with hundreds of people recording the videos I was not creative enough to Catch their IP in my PHP handler and then correlate it with the correct video information. The video information goes from A-->B-->phphandler if I were to get the ip from A-->phphandler I wasn't sure I would be able to pair the information on the other side.

Comment: I tried this; however, It prevented the webcam recorder from loading in. Is there anyway to just simply get the result of `function getIP(json)` into a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

The second code example does not work because the variable is only given a value inside of a callback function, which means the alert,which runs synchronously, runs as soon as the javascript interpreter starts reading and running the code line by line, but the getIP function is only called later on when the jsonp request returns a response. Your first code example was the right way to go.

Comment: I was just using alert() to try and verify if the data I wanted was stored into the variable. How else can I store the result of that function into a global variable?

Comment: If you're waiting on the result of a call to an external script, you need to do things asynchronously so the external call returns first, that's why you're registering the getIP function as a callback in the first place I'd imagine. In that case, you have to make sure the rest of your code waits.

Answer (score 0):

As Rob says, you're expecting the code to run synchronously but that isn't the case.

Here's a small edit of your code snippet that will work, basically I've wrapped the alert in a function, I then call that function once the getIP function has finished executing.

```
<script>

var clientIP = ''

function getIP(json) {
    clientIP = json.ip;
    alertClientIp();
}

function alertClientIp () {
    alert(clientIP);
}

</script>
```

The code design of the above snippet is a bit nasty, if you only need to use the client IP once, then don't bother storing it as a variable, just pass it to the function which executes you "automated webhook POST" logic.

```
<script>

    function getIP(json) {
        clientIP = json.ip;
        alertClientIp();
    }

    //Accept the client_ip as a param
    function webhookLogic (client_ip) {

       //Execute your logic with the client_ip, 
       //for simplicity I'll stick to your alert.

       alert(client_ip);
    }

    </script>
```

**With regards to your edit**

It looks like you have the two sets of logic placed in two separate script elements, could you not merge them into one?

```
<script>

    function getIP(json) {
        clientIP = json.ip;
        alertClientIp();
    }

    //Accept the client_ip as a param
    function webhookLogic (client_ip) {

       //Execute your logic with the client_ip, 
       //for simplicity i'll stick to your alert.

       //Trigger your video wrapper code, unsure if 
       //if this method of execution will break your app...
       videoWrapper(client_ip);
    }

     //Your video code from your latest edit
    function videoWrapper (client_ip) {
        var IPADDRESSVARIABLE = client_ip;
        var size = {width:400,height:330};
        var flashvars = {qualityurl: "avq/300p.xml",accountHash:"BUNCHOFRANDOMSTUFF", eid:2, showMenu:"true", mrt:120,sis:0,asv:1,mv:0, payload: IPADDRESSVARIABLE};
    (function() {var pipe = document.createElement('script'); pipe.type = 'text/javascript'; pipe.async = true;pipe.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 's1.addpipe.com/1.3/pipe.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(pipe, s);})();
   }
    </script>
```

If that chain of execution breaks your app then I think you need to go back to the drawing board with regards to the composition of your question, it's clear what you want to do but your question lacks a bit of meta-data as to how this logic all "fits together".

Comment: So the webhook is through a third party that sends a payload of JSON when a webcam video is recorded. I can add custom data to the payload from their server by adding a variable, or string to the flash vars in the embed code. I will update my original question so you can see.

Comment: Yes I would merge them into one, the webhook logic is automatically executed from the AddPipe server when my video is uploaded to them. The only thing I need is to get the result of `function getIP(json)` into a global variable so that I can add it in the embed code. That is the reason I used return in my original code. I don't have any webhook logic on my side whatsoever.

Comment: Im so used to python that it is just as simple as `myVar = ' '     def myFunction():      myVar = xyz         myFunction()`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
function getIP(json) {
    return json.ip;
}

var json = { "ip": "111.22.33.44"}
var clientIP = getIP(json);

alert(clientIP);
```

Comment: I need to be able to avoid hard coding the IP address as I need it to be happening in the background as hundreds of people access my app.

Comment: @ChaceMcguyer I hardcoded in the answer because Its just a demo. Obviously it will be dynamic.